# My app updates won't show in the google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to update an app in the google play store.
The google developer FAQ says it can take up to 24 hours after publishing before it's visable.
I updated an apk and the store description 26+ hours ago, then again about 22 hours ago and another new version around 6 hours ago. But when I visit the store I still see an old version from 3 days ago and the old description.
When I release new versions in such a short period, does it mean the checking/review will be reset and only the last one will be published, or will every version be available in the submitted order when they are ready?

Update:
It's now "on the line". It seems when you push updates very fast they will not be shown, because the review process will always start from the beginning. So you should consider to wait after every update until it's shown. Or Google just had some problems these days.

Comment: Hi You found any solution.. As Same issue i am facing now. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks google might  have introduced new internal system of updating new version. My app was published 2 days ago but still not showing the latest version in play store, though I got email that my update is live within 1 hour.

Comment: Yes. Iam also having same issue. Not showing the latest version in play store, though I got email that my update is live within 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Check again your `Google Play Developer Console`.

Be sure your app is supported in your device where you are expecting to see your app, and `STATUS` is `in Prod`.
Older .apk´s must be `Unpublised`

I had this situation my app had an error and my status was "`Unpublished`"

[image]

Comment: It says Supported devices: 4812 and exluded devices: 0. The newest version says published all older apks are unpublished. [Screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img541/1959/o7lx.png)  (in german) In the store I see version 4 (1.3)

Comment: ok @cubei I see, everything is right!, if your current app version is 1.7, you just have to wait =(, be patient =).

Comment: I didn't upload an apk with the versioncode 5, but that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: definitely no, have you tried with other device trying to download the new version? I was thinking if you look the device in "Liste ansehen", I remember two years ago i had a "huawei" phone that was not listed, so I can´t download my app.

Comment: I'm looking at the webpage with my notebook. I checked the playstore app with my tablet, my phone, and 2 other phones. All show the old description with old app version.